# Reordering columns in silverlight datagrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, datagridcolumn

I'm writing Silverlight application and I have a datagrid in which first two columns' positions are fixed, but others can be reordered. If I simply set CanUserReorder property to true/false respectively, than I can still take 3rd column and put it into 1st position.

What can I do to implement behaviour I need?

**For now I can only think of manually handling ColumnReordered/ColumnReordering events in code-behind. Are there any solutions I am missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the FrozenColumnCount of the datagrid.

```
dgMyGrid.FrozenColumnCount = 2
```

That will prevent the first two columns from being moved.  As a "bonus", they won't scroll while others do (though this may not be what you want...)

From MSDN Blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/10/15/freezing-columns-in-the-silverlight-datagrid.aspx

Comment: In fact, that's exactly what i want! Thanks for the hint!